# python - How to resume a FOR LOOP if the program crashes?

Tags: python, for-loop

This program is very dependant on the network, and sometimes the network crashes.

There is a way to resume a "for loop" in case that the program crashes, the next time I star the program it will start in the same user that the program have crashed.

The code:

```
users = [
           {'username': 'user1', 'email': 'mail1@mail.com'},
           {'username': 'user2', 'email': 'mail2@mail.com'},
           {'username': 'user3', 'email': 'mail3@mail.com'},
           {'username': 'user4', 'email': 'mail4@mail.com'},
        ]

try:
    text_file = open("current_username.txt", "w")

    for item in users:
        text_file.seek(0)
        text_file.truncate()
        text_file.write(item['username'])
        # BEGIN, some relevant code that sometimes crashes and don't is code dependent
        # ...
        # END, some relevant code that sometimes crashes and don't is code dependent

    text_file.close()
except:
    text_file.close()
```

Any clue on how the next time I start the program, it will start on the same "username" that crashed the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your same code and made some tweaks

```
users = [
           {'username': 'user1', 'email': 'mail1@mail.com'},
           {'username': 'user2', 'email': 'mail2@mail.com'},
           {'username': 'user3', 'email': 'mail3@mail.com'},
           {'username': 'user4', 'email': 'mail4@mail.com'},
        ]

try:
    #Open file to Read / Write, note the 'r+'
    text_file = open("current_username.txt", "r+")
    text_file.seek(0)

    #Read the last user written in the file
    current_user = text_file.readline()
    last_index = 0

    if current_user is not '':
        for last in range(len(users)):
            if users[last]['username'] == current_user:
                last_index = last
                break

    for index in range(last_index, len(users)):
        text_file.seek(0)
        text_file.truncate()
        text_file.write(users[index]['username'])
        print(users[index])

        # BEGIN, some relevant code that sometimes crashes and don't is code dependent
        # ...
        # END, some relevant code that sometimes crashes and don't is code dependent

    text_file.seek(0)
    text_file.truncate()
    text_file.write('')
    text_file.close()

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    text_file.close()
```

If the loop ends anormally, the `current_username.txt` have the last user, and the first loop seek the last index and start there, in the other hand, if `current_username.txt` doesn't have any data, the next program execution starts from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

It does depend on how critical recovery is.

For a simple, non critical approach, using a context manager and `with` statement will do a better job of handling exceptions and making it more likely your initial `write(username)` is written to file so you can use that to recover the current user:

```
with open("current_username.txt", "w") as text_file:
    for item in users:
        text_file.seek(0)
        ...
```

The `with` will close the file and release resources when it exits or if there is an exception.

For recovery you could consume an iterator up to the current user using `itertools.takewhile()`, e.g. (pseudocode):

```
current_user = open("current_username.txt").readline().strip()
recover(current_user)
remaining_users = iter(users)
discard = itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x['username'] != current_user, remaining_users)
collections.deque(discard, maxlen=0)

for item in remaining_users:
    ...
```

Comment: Showing how to *write* that file in a way that guarantees that there won't be partial content (or that it won't be empty &c in the case of an unexpected crash) is an important element to completing this answer.

Comment: Related: [Getting Atomic Writes Right](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2014/07/getting-atomic-writes-right.html)

Answer (score 1):

If your crash is not code dependant I suggest a different iteration using an index, then store this index in your hard disk.
I'm not really a fan of this solution, but this might be what you asked for:

```
users = [
       {1:{'username': 'user1', 'email': 'mail1@mail.com'}},
       {2:{'username': 'user2', 'email': 'mail2@mail.com'}},
       {3:{'username': 'user3', 'email': 'mail3@mail.com'}},
       {4:{'username': 'user4', 'email': 'mail4@mail.com'}},
    ]
counter = 0
try:
    saveFile = open('saveFile.txt','r')
    counter = int(saveFile.read())
    saveFile.close()
except IOError:
    pass

try:
    text_file = open("current_username.txt", "w")
    for i in range(counter,len(users)):
        item = users[i]
        text_file.seek(0)
        text_file.truncate()
        text_file.write(item['username'])
        # BEGIN, some relevant code that sometimes crashes and don't is     code dependent
        # ...
        # END, some relevant code that sometimes crashes and don't is code dependent
        counter = i
    text_file.close()
except:
    saveFile = open('savefile.txt','w+')
    saveFile.write(counter)
    saveFile.close()
    text_file.close()
```

Still, this will not save you if the crash occurs while you're processing data since the operations are not atomic. The progress is saved when you finish the processing of that `item`, so you could have duplicate data, I think.

Comment: When you `open('savefile.txt', 'w+')`, that truncates the original contents. A crash at that point will leave the counter completely empty. As such, this is not a safe way to do an atomic file update.

Comment: I intend to erase the progress of the counter, since I need to overwrite it each time I save a new counter.

Comment: But the problem is you have an instant when the file is temporarily empty, so if the power is pulled (or you get a SIGKILL) at the wrong time, the next invocation of the program *doesn't* restart where this one left off. There are other, better ways to replace a file's contents that don't have this problem. See the link I posted in a comment on the answer by AChampion.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is probably to wrap the stuff inside the `for` loop in another loop, and exit only when successful. Also, you probably want to use with `with as` construct.

```
with open("current_username.txt", "w") as text_file:

    for item in users:
        text_file.seek(0)
        text_file.truncate()
        text_file.write(item['username'])

        while True:
            try:
                # BEGIN, some relevant code that sometimes crashes and don't is code dependent
                # ...
                # END, some relevant code that sometimes crashes and don't is code dependent
            except: # Should probably specify a specific error type
                # Possibly undo changes made above
                pass
            else:
                break

# text_file is automatically closed when the `with` block is exited
```

Comment: If you get power yanked or a SIGKILL between the `truncate()` and the `write()`, we're back at the beginning. *And* you need to call `flush()` to make sure the write is actually executed on promptly.

Comment: True, I was focusing more on gracefully handling a (software) crash than continuing from an arbitrary crash

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html). It's the easiest way to serialize objects, and can be used to save states.

You may do something like this to restore a loop:

```
import pickle

'''
Your other code here
'''
global REGISTRY    
start = pickle.loads(REGISTRY) if REGISTRY else 0
for i in xrange(start, len(users)):
    text_file.seek(0)
    text_file.truncate()
    text_file.write(item['username'])
    REGISTRY = pickle.dumps(i)
```

Comment: If you don't flush your write, there's no guarantee it won't just be sitting in buffer unflushed in the event of a `SIGKILL`. And see my comments on prior answers about the race conditions caused by this general approach.